# Installing MySQl 5.5 on CentOS 6 dependencies conflict

Tags: mysql, centos6

I installed mysql on my centos 6 yesterday but I wasb't aware that it's installing mysql 5.1 which is an outdated version. Now I've remove old version and all it's dependencies, but when I try to install MySQL 5.5 yum says there are problems because of mysql-libs conflicting with new one.

```
[root@Pooya /]# yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.kiewel-online.ch
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: ftp.linux.org.tr
 * ius: download.srv.ro
 * remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.5.28-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.28-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-5.5.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.28-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql-server-5.5.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.28-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql51-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.66-1.ius.el5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                       Arch                                  Version                                           Repository                           Size
=================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql                                         x86_64                                5.5.28-1.el6.remi                                 remi                                5.7 M
 mysql-server                                  x86_64                                5.5.28-1.el6.remi                                 remi                                 10 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql-libs                                    x86_64                                5.5.28-1.el6.remi                                 remi                                771 k
 mysql51-libs                                  x86_64                                5.1.66-1.ius.el5                                  ius                                 1.7 M
 perl-DBD-MySQL                                x86_64                                4.013-3.el6                                       base                                134 k

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================================================================================
```

As you can see it's downloading both mysql libs for mysql 5.5 and 5.1! How can I fix that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was because of repositories conflict, which some of them are storing newer version of mySQL and some of them are just holding their old, sure-to-be-stable versions.

I disabled those repositories and kept only the ones which are holding latest stable version of MySQL and problem fixed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not likely to encourage people to answer any new questions you post.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have wrote 2 comments under your answer which by the way you didn't even bothered to answer one of them.

Comment: @faridv I think Michael took issue with the fact that his answer pointed to the solution, yet you wrote a nearly identical Answer and Accepted your own instead of his. This sort of behavior is highly frowned upon on [SE].

Comment: @ChrisS I'm sure his answer is not completely correct but it helped me to find my solution, I asked him to guide me more clearly on his answer by commenting on his answer but he didn't answered them and now I have answered my question by myself and shared my own solution. What else could I do, remove my question or live it be for the end of time unanswered for the people who may have the same question?!

Comment: Your "answer" says nothing more than my answer does, and it certainly does not go into the detail you claim to have wanted.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Problem was not only becase of `IUS` repo, I had to disable other repos like `base` and etc. to install latest version of mysql. Now why are these repos storing different versions of a package? Which one of these issues have you mentioned in your answer??

Comment: If you disabled the `base` repo, then you certainly deserve the downvote, and another besides. That's going to cause you all sorts of trouble in future.

Comment: @MichaelHampton first of all, it was only temporary to install mysql. next, instead of down-voting me, complete your answer and add details to it, so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the IUS community repo installed and enabled. Disable this repo, as it conflicts with remi (and many other repositories).

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: It seems that I have too many repositories which are conflicting each other! Which repositories should I keep and which I should disable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem that needs to be fixed.  You have different libraries that depend on different versions of the libmysqlclient.so, the DB server can talk to clients of different versions safely.  In this case MySQL comes with some utilities written in perl and the perl MySQL library is built against the 5.1 version of the client library, shouldn't affect the utilities in any way.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install MySql 5.5 on a CentOS 6 and over-right conflicts in mysql-libs you have to:

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace
wget https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum install mysql.`uname -i` yum-plugin-replace
yum replace mysql --replace-with mysql55w
yum replace mysql-libs --replace-with mysql55w-libs
yum install mysql55w-server mysql55w
service mysqld start
mysql_secure_installation
```

Enter your password and done!